# perform join python returns a "none"

Tags: list, join, python-3.x

my "output" seems to populate fine however when I perform the join I get "none returned.

Any ideas?

```
def englishify_sentence(s):
    """English"""
    words = s.lower()
    words = words.split()# splits sentence into individual words
    output = []

    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i].endswith("way"):
            opt1 = words[i][:-3]
            letters = list(opt1)#breaks given word into individual letters
            translate = ("("+opt1+" or "+"w"+opt1+")")
            output.append(translate)
        else:
            opt2 = words[i][:-2]
            opt2_letters = list(opt2)#breaks given word into individual letters
            first_letter = (opt2_letters.pop(-1))
            opt3 = words[i][:-3]
            translate2 = (first_letter+opt3)
            output.append(translate2)
            english = " ".join(output)#removes speech marks and creates a "real" word
    print(output)

english = englishify_sentence("oday ouyay antway anway eggway")
print(english)
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return the value.

```
return english
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it the print(output) that's giving you a none or the print(english)?